# Is it better practice to declare variables inside an if statement or outside?

Tags: javascript, optimization, coding-style

I'm cleaning up some Javascript code that calculates how many people have downloaded something out of those have been assigned to download it. I came across this simple statement:

```
var percent_downloads = 0;
if (users_assigned != 0) {
   percent_downloads = total_downloads / users_assigned;
}
```

I'm considering rewriting the code to declare the variable inside an if-else statement, like so:

```
if (users_assigned != 0) {
    var percent_downloads = total_downloads / users_assigned;
} else {
    var percent_downloads = 0;
}
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906414/is-it-wrong-to-declare-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement-in-javascript), they're both equally functional, but which is better code?

Comment: I think this is more of a preference thing. However, declaring it (even as nothing with var percent_downloads;) before ever using it is a more common apporach, I think.

Comment: it's a scope issue.  if the variable has no use beyond being declared and initialized within the `if` then there is no point in having it and indeed good compilers will even optimize that code out.  "Better" is subjective, but all things being equal, the less text you use the more readable and understandable code becomes at a glance

Comment: @fnostro Except that there are only two scopes in JS, and the variable *will* exist outside the `if` statement because of hoisting. When `let` statements are better supported this will be less true.

Comment: Also consider `var percent_downloads; if(…) percent_downloads = …; else percent_downloads = …;` and `var percent_downloads = (…) ? … : …;`.

Comment: @DaveNewton: hoisting is unfortunate in JS, it goes against natural readability.  In the OP example, assuming `percent_downloads` is used elsewhere, the second example may be JS legal, but really does not convey intent.  IMO, it is better to write code as if scope were a factor, even in JS.

Answer (score 2):

This is opinion-based, with the well-known technical caveat regarding JavaScript scoping. This comment is too long for a comment, though.

In *this* case, I'd use a ternary, and skip the question altogether, because this code is short. Or I'd leave it alone, since the rewrite is longer and doesn't (necessarily) add much context (but see below regarding longer functions).

In a suitably-short functions I'm not convinced it matters very much. The reason for declaring variables at the top of the function is because that's where their declaration ends up *anyway*, and it avoids any confusion regarding scoping rules and point of initialization.

In longer functions you have to scan (read: think too much) for declarations, make sure scoping sanity prevails, and make sure you're not accidentally referencing a variable before it's been *initialized* (which it is in this snippet).

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Dave Newton "This comment is too long for a comment, though." Trying to explain it in a simple way.

1. JavaScript has no facility for block scope. [Ref](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch3.md#blocks-as-scopes)
2. all declarations, both variables and functions, are processed first, before any part of your code is executed. [Hoisting-Ref](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch4.md)

**Your Code**

```
if (users_assigned != 0) {
    var percent_downloads = total_downloads / users_assigned;
} else {
    var percent_downloads = 0;
}
```

**How it is interpreted by JS engine**

1. found : a variable `percent_downloads;` Check scope, is it there, if yes ignore else create variable. [For More ref: Nested Scope](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch1.md#nested-scope)
2. execute: Code

Finally Code gets executed as:

```
if (users_assigned != 0) {
    percent_downloads = total_downloads / users_assigned;
} else {
    percent_downloads = 0;
}
```

So, they're both equally functional.

**One more example, please check comments in code for better understanding**

**Case 1**

```
var foo = true;
console.log(bar)//found a variable not declared yet - create&set value as undefined
if (foo) {
    var bar = foo * 2;  //already declared set new value
    console.log( bar ); //print new value
}
    console.log( bar ); //print new value
//output
//undefined
//2
//2
```

**Case 2**

```
var foo = false;
console.log(bar)//found a variable not declared yet - create&set value as undefined
if (foo) {
    var bar = foo * 2; //code skipped - value is undefined
    console.log( bar ); //code skipped - value is undefined
}
    console.log( bar );  //value is undefined
//output
//undefined
//undefined
//undefined
```